# How to change phone_number format upon creation of a AWS Cognito User Pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm creating a new Cognito User Pool in AWS. One of user attributes is phone number. User Pool documentation states that phone number format must start with a plus sign (+), something like "+14325551212" for United States. But what about other countries formats. I've tried with Brazilian format and got the following error: "Invalid phone number format". 
So, do only US numbers allowed ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have tried that does not work?

Comment: @doorstuck, This is a part of code. So, if phone is in US format the code works fine, if it is "+5551993399000" (Brazilian format) the code fails:

     `var params = {
        
        ClientId: '...',
        Password: password,
        Username: '...',
        UserAttributes: [
       
            {
                Name: 'phone_number',
                Value: phone
            }
      ]
    };
    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
   cognitoidentityserviceprovider.signUp(params, function(err, data) {
    //Implementation
}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am on the Cognito team and we recently deployed a fix that should take care of this issue. So those phone numbers should work now.

Comment: well, on the London instance of cognito I am putting in a uk number *exactly* as specified and its rejecting it. "+447909123456". what gives?

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar problem right now, here is my error: 
`Error executing "SignUp" on "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: POST https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com resulted in a 400 Bad Request response:{"__type":"InvalidParameterException","message":"Invalid phone number format."} InvalidParameterException (client): Invalid phone number format. - {"__type":"InvalidParameterException","message":"Invalid phone number format."}`. Any help?

Comment: Hi @IonutTrestian, same error message here. The system also does NOT accept Australian numbers. Even if I prefix "+61" using JS, AWS still returns "Invalid phone number format." error. Very annoying.

Comment: Is it working particularly for some regions, as I in eu-west-1 and I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

Cognito uses SNS to send SMS messages so all the countries in the list below should be supported (Brazil is in the list):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html

AWS strongly encourages E.164 number formatting for all phone numbers both in the ‘to’ and ‘from’ (when applicable) fields. I'm not really familiar with Brazilian numbers, is there anything particular about that specific one?

Comment: Hi @Ionut Trestian. Actually there is nothing peculiar with Brazilian numbers. See this example "+55 51 99442 7676" (with no blank spaces). That's why I can't understand why this number raises that error.

Comment: Can you use the SNS console to send SMS messages to that particular phone number or it give the exact same error? You can try this by going to the SNS console and clicking on SMS Text Messaging (it is only available in certain regions such as US East 1).

Comment: I've already did it. In SNS console sms goes fine.So I realized that after country code (+55), comes the two digit for Area Code, im this cases area ; code ls 51. Here is the problem, if we set as area code one of the following: 11, 21, 41 no error is raised. However, if area code is 51, error message says that is an invalid  format. Actually, it's a normal number. So, if number is +5511994427578 everything is alright. In the other hand, if number is +5551994427565 an error raises

Answer (score 0):

Brasil is +55. :-/ the + = 00. If you want "Brazilian numbers" then it would be like

+55 61 999998888